# SQL Report Grouping

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have a SQL Report similar to the one below:

[image]

What I want is for example:

Boston

1. Number 1
2. Number 2
3. Number 3

Basically, I only want to see Boston once, and then expand to the multiple numbers...

How can I do this?

Here are my Row Groups:
[image]

Comment: Your row grouping looks messed....what row groups do you have defined?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my row groups...

Comment: Thats confusing.   You'll want to have market in there (likely as the top group)...I'm not sure what the static groupings are and why you would group by a static value

Comment: What is Market ?  Is it a column in a database ? and what is 812 ? was it retrieved from a different column

Comment: Yes, market is a column in a database

Comment: Save a copy before doing this...but I think you'll want to delete all the groupings and add only market.  Give it a run and see how close it is to what you want.

Comment: you can also do DISTINCT  on the field name .... depending on the DDL of your table

Comment: 8112 was retrieved from another column

Comment: @NullSoulException - confused by your comments here, have you designed anything in report builder?  distinct select doesn't resolve a row grouping issue, this isn't a sql code problem.  I think he'll need to remove all groupings (keep the columns when it asks) and re-add the groupings that he wants

Comment: @Twelfth So my comment was adding "salt to the pain" ..  I probably did, but user3147424 is the one to blame.....I was just trying to understand the layout of the table where he is getting the data from .

Comment: @NullSoulException no need to blame, I'm just trying to group my report.

Comment: No worries Nullsoulexception (nice name btw)...question should be tagged better.  I changed the tags to drop the SQL and add report builder...it's more accurate with where his question is.  User3147424 - Did you use an existing report as a framework and alter it with this SQL statement by any chance?